# Для календаря из CTE показать рабочие и не рабочие дни

Tags: sql

Всем привет, изучая тему values - наткнулся на такое задание - Из данного календаря показать количество рабочих и не рабочих дней. Вот CTE

```
WITH cal(SHOP_ID, MON, TUE, WED, THUR, FRI, SAT, SUN) AS (VALUES(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Я не понимаю с чего стоит составлять запрос. Результат должен быть таким:

```
SHOP_ID     DAY_TYPE      DAY_COUNT
1           Working       3
1           Non-working   4
2           Working       4
2           Non-Working   3
```

Столбец DAY_COUNT должен быть рассчитан с помощью SUM или COUNT и GROUP BY.
В общем составил такой запрос, но нужно как то посчитать кол-во дней и приписать в отдельном столбце рабочий\нерабочий

```
WITH caln(SHOP_ID, MON, TUE, WED, THUR, FRI, SAT, SUN) AS (VALUES(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), (2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)) 
SELECT SHOP_ID, DAY_COUNT 
FROM caln, 
TABLE(values(MON), (TUE), (WED), (THUR), (FRI), (SAT), (SUN)) AS tab(DAY_COUNT) 
ORDER BY SHOP_ID
```

Comment: Столбец DAY_TYPE можешь заполнить с помощью оператора CASE. Если SAT или SUN -> Non-Working, ELSE Working

Comment: UNPIVOT, а потом уже агрегация.

Comment: спасибо конечно, но многое мне не знакомо, может есть какой то другой вариант?

Comment: Наишите код, пожалуйста, через unpivot ничего не получается

Comment: @Akina Вы не могли бы подробнее описать что нужно сделать в этой задаче или хотя бы часть кода написать, а то я уже 3й день ничего не могу придумать

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Comment: @Akina что здесь не правильно, я хочу транспонировать и посмотреть для начала
SELECT SHOP_ID, combo, values_id 
FROM caln, 
TABLE(values(MON, '10'), (TUE, '20'), (WED, '30'), (THUR, '40'), (FRI, '50'), (SAT, '50'), (SUN, '50')) AS tab(combo, values_id) 
ORDER BY SHOP_ID, values_id - из этого всего я хочу получить 3 столбца - 1) айдишники, 2) значения которые находятся в оригинальных столбцах, 3) присвоеные айдишники